# Connect to ssh remote host (which is in vpn network) times out

Tags: ssh, timeout, vpn, remote-server

I try to connect to a ssh host which is located in a remote vpn network. Once connected with my vpn client I am able to ping the ssh host. The ssh connection via a remote desktop session from a different machine within the vpn network works fine. SuSEfirewall2 is configured for routing port 22 to the sshd service.

When I now try to ssh from my vpn client machine, the operation times out:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.61.xx port 22: Operation timed out
```

The IP address that I get from the vpn client is xxx.xxx.60.xx!

Is there anything that needs to be considered for ssh-service setup when the host is within a remote vpn network?

Answer (score 1):

No, VPN should not make any difference.

The fact that ping works but ssh doesn't seems to suggest at a problem with your firewall-config for ssh service.

Can you use the ssh service from the ssh-server itself or local network?

Comment: Yes - I can use the ssh service from the ssh-server itself AND from another host within the local network. Just the connection from the vpn connected client times out... That is weird.